# Is there any way to bind jsonpath dynamically in angular 6

Tags: json, angular6, jsonpath

I am creating a reusable component in which I can pass any dynamic json so he'll able to handle that

what I tried is

**mycomponent.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let Node of items">
{{ Node[getPath()]}}<br>
</div>
```

**mycomponent.ts:**

```
@Input()
path:any;

@Input()
items:any;

  getData(){
    var String="";
    var data=this.path.split('.');
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      if(i==0){
        String+="'"+data[i]+"']";
      }else if(i+1==data.length){
        String+="['"+data[i]+"'";
      }
      else{
        String+="['"+data[i]+"']";
      }
    }
    return String;
  }
```

The output of **getData()** function is like

'related']['name'

because the reasone is 
in **mycomponent.html** i am using 
{{Node[getData()]}}

so basically im trying to do is
**{{Node['related']['name']}}**

**MainComponent.html:**

```
<my-component path="related.name" items={{items}}></my-component>
```

**Input Array**

```
[
   {
    "related": [
      {
        "name": "first"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "related": [
      {
        "name": "second"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

my expected output is like

first
second

I want to create that component as resuable so i can use anywhere in my project so give any suggestion to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

When you create a dynamic component to handle the input JSON.
You could do two ways

1. Create the component.

   ```
           mycomponent.html:
           mycomponent.ts
   ```

   mycomponent
      @Input()
   items:any;

When you integrate the component as any child then you could do as

```
<mycomponent [items]="items"></mycomponent>
```

or when you want to invoke as popup
then

```
let ngModelRef : NgbModalRef = this.ngbModalService.open(mycomponent );
    ngModelRef.componentInstance.items= items;
    return ngModelRef;
```